# Take action after activity setup is complete

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I want to take an action after the activity is finished with the setup.
What I need is not just simply writing the code after everything else in the activiy, because the are some display measures needs to be done, and I need to calculate only after the activity is fully setup/

I tried using

```
final ViewTreeObserver observer = mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
           //whatever I want to do...
}
});
```

this did work but it made my app to crash with only

```
` `"01-30 14:21:55.615: A/libc(4867): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00022588 (code=1), thread 4867 (m.fgdvir.ezlist)"
```

in the error log

pleas help!
thanks

Comment: Try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html#addIdleHandler(android.os.MessageQueue.IdleHandler)

Answer (score 0):

You can place the code in `onResume()`, which is called back to your Activity once the UI has been set up and the User is able to interact with it.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   // ... code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so after some digging, I noticed that my solution was right(not sure if is the best way, but it worked for me), but I had 1 thing missing - after calling the **onGlobalLayouLtListener** I needed to **remove** the listener. so the code that I'm using that works is as folowing:

```
final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                //The things I need to be done after activity setup is finished.

            }

        });
```

btw - I noticed that id really dosn't metter which view inside the activity, I attach to the OnGlobalLayoutListener, you can really choose which ever you'd like.